# How to get values from SVG file using QT

Tags: c++, qt, svg

I am in need of a way to get the values inside the svg file in QT using the XMLStreamReader.. How do I do that?

Here's the values inside an SVG file.

[image]

And here's what I've tried yet. I'm trying to printout the values if I'm getting something. I'm new to QT by the way.

```
xmlFile = new QFile("composition.svg");

if (!xmlFile->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
                qDebug() << ("Load XML File Problem");

xmlReader = new QXmlStreamReader(xmlFile);


//Parse the XML until we reach end of it
while(!xmlReader->atEnd() && !xmlReader->hasError()) {
        // Read next element
        QXmlStreamReader::TokenType token = xmlReader->readNext();
        //If token is just StartDocument - go to next
        if(token == QXmlStreamReader::StartDocument) {
                continue;
        }
        //If token is StartElement - read it
        if(token == QXmlStreamReader::StartElement) {

                if(xmlReader->name() == "g") {
                        continue;
                }

                if(xmlReader->name() == "g") {
                    qDebug() << xmlReader->readElementText();
                    //fprintf(stderr, xmlReader->readElementText().toLatin1());
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while(!xmlReader->atEnd() && !xmlReader->hasError()) {
        // Read next element
        QXmlStreamReader::TokenType token = xmlReader->readNext();
        //If token is just StartDocument - go to next
        if(token == QXmlStreamReader::StartDocument)
                continue;
        //If token is StartElement - read it
        if(token == QXmlStreamReader::StartElement)
        {
            if(xmlReader->name() == "g")
                   continue;
            if(xmlReader->name() == "polygon")
            {
                foreach(const QXmlStreamAttribute &attr, xmlReader->attributes())
                {
                    if (attr.name().toString() == QLatin1String("style"))
                    {
                        qDebug() << attr.value().toLatin1();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I needed to loop on the attributes/nodes to get some of its values.